Cant delete Swift Data model with a Predicate
I have a SwiftData app with a model:
@Model final class User: ObservableObject, Equatable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID = UUID()
    //...
}

When I try to delete it with this code:
List { ForEach(users, id: \.id) { aUser in

    //...

    HStack {
        Text("\(aUser.name)")
        Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
            .foregroundStyle(.red)
            .onTapGesture {
                let theID = aUser.id // < grab reference to the selected user or else the Predicate crashes
                print(theID.uuidString) // < console shows expected String

                // vv The below will crash if I use: anItem.id.uuidString == theID.uuidString
                try? modelContext.delete(model: User.self, where: #Predicate<User> { anItem in anItem.id ==  theID })

                print(modelContext.hasChanges) // < **always** false
                modelContext.save()
            }
        }

    // ...
}

It appears to delete a user (occasionally not the correct one), but between startups the deleted user will reappear.
Losing the #Predicate:
    for i in 0 ..< users.count {
        if users[I].id.uuidString == theID.uuidString {
            modelContext.delete(users[i])
            break
        }
    }

print(modelContext.hasChanges) // < prints true when the user is found

All works fine and the user is permanently removed.
Although I imagined comparing UUID might always produce a false (the instances of two UUIDs can never be the same, can they?), that would mean the user never being deleted. But, to reiterate, a user is removed only to reappear the next time the app is started.
I'd like to use a Predicate from a code golf type of point of view, so can someone explain how the first code listing doesn't work.
EDIT
As per @Sweeper's comment, here's a SwiftFiddle. It appears to be more stable in deleting an Item but the method of deleting via Predicate will still always produce false for .hasChanged. Possible bug?
https://swiftfiddle.com/d6szvrb4tjfsnayswkehp5l6zm

Likely unrelated but ObservableObject needs to be remove. The new observation replaces it.

I cannot reproduce this on iOS 18.0. The model objects are deleted as expected. Please show a [mcve].

Interestingly, even without try? modelContext.save(), the model objects are deleted on the next launch. It seems like the overload of delete that takes a predicate automatically saves the context (!?)

Note, @Model final class ... already conforms to Identifiable, that is, it already has a id, no real need to use another one.

Why use modelContext.delete(model:) with a predicate instead of using the dedicated delete method for a single object, modelContext.delete(aUser)?

@Sweeper : updated with fiddle. The predicate deletion method doesn't seem to affect the hasChanges flag in the context.

@workingdogsupportUkraine : agreed - I think it's a hangover from long, long time ago!

@Todd I can reproduce the values of hasChanges, and I also think that's a bug. But I cannot reproduce "a user is removed only to reappear the next time the app is started".

@JoakimDanielson : yep, the simplest method always works! That's fine for this instance but there are others where I'll have more than one model to delete. It's a good suggestion and one I'll implement in this instance.

@Sweeper : looks like I'm dealing with two bugs then. One in my code somewhere and one with SwoftData. I think, if others have the same observations as you, then I should probably close it and file a report....

I believe we should see the delete(model:where:) function as a form of batch delete function that for performance reasons works directly agains the data store and doesn't update the internal state of the ModelContext object so for me it's not a bug that hasChanges isn't set to true.

remember when you call save it is saving all the changes to all models in the context not just the one edit you just made, so its best to let auto-save handle it so its done at the right time.

@JoakimDanielson so when I save, the model context could reset the data store by writing the old data that’s held in memory?

No I think you read to much into what I said about not updating the internal state. I meant before doing the delete, once the delete operation is performed and committed it will update the state of any affected objects.
